# Organizing revel tests into sub packages

Tags: testing, go, revel

We are currently working with a revel project, and the number of tests are already getting out of hand. I'm wanting to create a few packages under the `tests` directory to separate out controller tests from model tests and so on (e.g. `tests/controllers/`, `tests/models/`, etc).

When I do this the revel test command stops seeing these files.

I found a recommendation online to trail my test command with `...`, but when I do this I get an error saying it failed to import my project.

Is this possible to do, or do all test files have to be within the `tests` directory? If it's possible, how do you run the tests in the sub-packages?

Comment: Unit tests must be in the same package, which means the same directory. You can only do blackbox testing from a separate directory.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the tests themselves into an importable package (i.e. not in a `_test.go` file), and then use them twice. The `_test.go` files in the subdirectories can be something like:

```
package subdir_test

import "github.com/blah/project/parent/subdir/tests"

func TestPackage(t *testing.T) {
    tests.Run(t)
}
```

Using [`TB.Run`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks) you can make things play nice with `go test` command line arguments:

```
package tests // subdir

import "testing"

func Run(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range testCases { // or whatever
        test.Run(t)
    }
}
```

And of course parent directories can just call their child directories' `Run` methods:

```
package parent_test

import (
    "testing"
    p "github.com/blah/project/parent/tests"
    s "github.com/blah/project/parent/subdir/tests"
)

func TestPackage(t *testing.T) {
    p.Run(t)
}

func TestSubPackages(t *testing.T) {
    s.Run(t)
}
```

I would recommend avoiding variants of `go list ./...` etc as lots of the tooling is not really prepared to handled that gracefully (for example running that with coverage does not produce a single combined report, complicating things for large projects, and it also lists vendored code which might not always make sense)

Comment: How does this work inside revel. Right now all of the tests are attached to the AppTest e.g. `func (t *AppTest) TestMethodName(){}`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant running via `go test` on the command line (that's where the `...` thing works, I guess the `revel` cli also supports it?). If you're only using revel style tests, it runs things in a non-standard way, so you'll basically have to instantiate [`revel/testing.TestSuite`](https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel/testing#TestSuite) and invoke the methods on that, but the same logic applies - tests are just functions and you can make them reuse each other.

Comment: Correction initialize the embedded `TestSuite` inside of `AppTest`, and invoke the methods on `AppTest`, obviously

Comment: Can you adjust your above code to suit it, I'm either getting circular imports or undefined 'AppTest' when I run it.

Comment: Well, my example was simply meant to show that you can call code that behaves as tests even if it's not in a test file, so depending on how you structure your code...  Revel itself uses [reflection](https://github.com/revel/modules/blob/master/testrunner/app/controllers/testrunner.go#L96) to invoke individual test methods by name. You can use this approach to invoke tests from other tests. But my suggestion was meant more generally: structure your test code so that you can call it arbitrarily, instead of trying to get it called by some mechanism that is a black box (`go test` or revel)